# Pycharm: dependent user environment variables

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables

I would like to set variables in pycharm environment. This works fine if I set normal environment variables by going to Run/Debug Configurations and adding more variables under Environment Variables.

However, if I add environment variables that are mutually dependent, then the normal string is displayed.

For example:

```
domain: google.com
url: https://${domain}
```

What I would like to see is what comes out when I call `os.environ.get('url')`:

Desired result: https://google.com

Which unfortunately appears as the result:

Actual result: https://${domain}

How can this dependency be mapped in pycharm so that the desired result is obtained?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to use the Pycharm plugin EnvFile. This made it possible to create an .env with which you could then use variables etc.